# Hierarchical Kendo Grid with local data

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How to create hierarchical kendo grid with local data? I have a "master" grid as follows:

```
<section id="master-item">
    <div class="panel">
                @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TheViewModel>()
            .Name("dealerFacilitySchedules")
            .DataSource(data => data
                .Ajax()
                .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.FacilityScheduleId))
                .ServerOperation(false)
            )
            .BindTo(Model.FacilitySchedules)
            .Columns(columns =>
            { /* colums definition */
            })
            /* other staff */
            .ClientDetailTemplateId("slave-item")
        )
    </div>
</section>
```

I don't know how to get "slave" item definition. How do I extract the item id in `BindTo` method?

```
<script id="slave-item" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TheSlaveItemViewModel>()
            .Name("dealerFacilitySchedule#=Id#")
            .DataSource(data => data
                .Ajax()
                .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.FacilityScheduleItemId))
                .ServerOperation(false)
            )
            .BindTo(Model.FacilitySchedules[ **How to add templated ID here??** ])
            .Columns(columns =>
            { /* definition of columns */
            })
            /* other config */
            .ToClientTemplate()
    )
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is still interested in that topic I haven't found out how to solve the problem using ASP.NET wrappers. However, it is possible to solve it using plain HTML and JS, as follows:

```
<section id="root-grid">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="grid"></div>
    </div>
</section>

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="slave-template">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="grid"></div>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.FacilitySchedules));
        var columns = [
            makeKendoColumn("ValidFrom", "@Resources.DealerFacility_ValidFrom", "{0:d}", "date"),
            // other columns
        ];
        var detailColumns = [
            // as above - columns definition
        ];

        OnRootScheduleGridInitialize(
            data,
            columns, detailColumns,
            $('#root-grid').find('.grid'));
    });
</script>
```

The scripts:

```
function OnRootScheduleGridInitialize(dataObject, columnsDefinition, subGridColumnsDefinition, $node) {
    $node.kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: dataObject,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        // root model fields definition
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 20
        },
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: {
            input: true,
            numeric: false
        },
        columns: columnsDefinition,

        detailTemplate: kendo.template($("#slave-template").html()),
        detailInit: OnDetailsScheduleInitializeFactory(subGridColumnsDefinition),
    });
}

function OnDetailsScheduleInitializeFactory(columnsDefinition) {
    return function (e) {
        var $row = e.detailRow;

        $row.find('.grid').kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                data: e.data.FacilityScheduleItems,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            // slave object model fields definition
                        }
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 20
            },
            scrollable: true,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: {
                input: true,
                numeric: false
            },
            columns: columnsDefinition,
        });
    };
}

function makeKendoDateColumn(columnName, columnLabel) {
    return makeKendoColumn(columnName, columnLabel, 'd', 'date');
}

function makeKendoNumericColumn(columnName, columnLabel) {
    return makeKendoColumn(columnName, columnLabel, 'n', 'number');
}

function makeKendoGenericColumn(columnName, columnLabel) {
    return {
        field: columnName,
        title: columnLabel,
        width: '100px',
    };
}

function makeKendoColumn(name, label, format, attrClass) {
    var maker = function (n, l, f, c) {
        var result = {
            width: '100px'
        };
        n(result);
        l(result);
        f(result);
        c(result);
        return result;
    }

    var nameDec = function (r) { r.field = name; };
    var labelDec = function (r) { r.title = label; };
    var attrDec = function () { };
    var formatDec = function () { };

    if (attrClass) {
        attrDec = function (r) { r.attributes = { "class": attrClass }; };
        formatDec = function (r) { r.format = format; };
    }
    else {
        if (format) {
            attrDec = function (r) { r.attributes = { "class": attrClass }; };
        }
    }

    return maker(nameDec, labelDec, formatDec, attrDec);
}
```

If you have any other solutions, please share it.

Answer (score -2):

Tthis is a snippet that portrays the syntax for getting values off of the Parent Grid. It's calling an Action Method that is populating the Model with Data from the current Opportunity

```
 .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Read(read => read.Action("GetDetailsAll", "Order", new {  opportunityId = "#=OpportunityId#" }))
```

Parent Row OppId is called through `#=OpportunityId#`

Comment: As far as I understand this creates a POST request to server which I don't want to. I want to work with local data.

Comment: It is the model used to render the page. Notice the `ServerOperation` set to `null` and `BindTo` method.

Comment: I'm sorry I am confused. In both Grids you have a bind to method that is attempting to Bind to the Same Model `Model.FacilitySchedules`.  How do they differ

Comment: `FacilitySchedules` is made of `TheSlaveItemViewModel`. That's why I types in the latter binding `**How to add templated ID here??**`